# N-dimensional histogram containing the maximum value of the weights that fall in each bin

Tags: python, numpy, histogram

I have a set of `M` points in N-dimensions, each of which has an associated "weight" value (basically, an array of `M` floats). Using `numpy`'s [histogramdd()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogramdd.html) I can generate the set's N-dimensional histogram.

If I use the `weights` parameter in `histogramdd()`, I get back:

> the sum of the weights belonging to the samples falling into each bin.

The code below shows hot to create these arrays:

```
import numpy as np

# N-dimensional M points.
N_dim, M = 3, 1000
points = np.random.uniform(0., 1., size=(M, N_dim))

# Weight for each point
weights = np.random.uniform(0., 1., M)

# N-dimensional histogram.
histo = np.histogramdd(points)[0]
# Histogram containing the sum of the weights in each bin.
weights_histo = np.histogramdd(points, weights=weights)[0]
```

Instead of this, I need to create the N-dimensional histogram for `points`, where the value stored in each bin is the *maximum weight value* out of all the weights associated to the points that fall within that bin.

I.e.: I need *only the maximum weight* stored in each bin, not the sum of all weights.

How could I do this?

Comment: Python version?

Comment: 2.7, but I'll take an answer for 3.x too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several `binned_statistic` functions in `scipy.stats`. 'max' is one of the default statistics, but you can use any callable as well.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import binned_statistic_dd

# N-dimensional M points.
N_dim, M = 3, 1000
points = np.random.uniform(0., 1., size=(M, N_dim))

# Weight for each point
weights = np.random.uniform(0., 1., M)

weights_histo, bin_edges, bin_indices = binned_statistic_dd(points,
                                                            weights,
                                                            statistic=np.max,
                                                            bins=5)

print weights_histo.shape # (5,5,5)
```